# Wordpress Admin User Deleted

Tags: wordpress, admin

Hi I have a serious problem.
I was working on wordpress and organizing with user account.
And mistakenly I deleted my admin account.
Then, I could not log in the dashboard.
I have the backup but I don't know what to do.
If someone knows how to solve this problem, please let me know.
Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [this blog post](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-the-wordpress-database-via-mysql/), you can add a admin user directly by SQL input.

If you have PhpMyAdmin, it will be as easy as login into it, navigate to `wp_users` table (replace `wp_` by your own prefi if you changed it during install) and execute this SQL :

```
INSERT INTO `your_databasename`.`wp_users` (`ID`, `user_login`, `user_pass`, `user_nicename`, `user_email`, `user_url`, `user_registered`, `user_activation_key`, `user_status`, `display_name`) VALUES ('4', 'your_username', MD5('your_password'), 'Your Name', 'your@email', 'Your Website', '2011-06-07 00:00:00', '', '0', 'Your Display name');

INSERT INTO `databasename`.`wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, '4', 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}');

INSERT INTO `databasename`.`wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, '4', 'wp_user_level', '10');
```

Remember to replace the values by your own (password, name, email, etc).

EDIT : markratledge's answer may be easier if you have a database backup ;)

Comment: Thank you Eliot! It seems like I dont have a database backup. So I will try to do your way. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Thank you very much! I successfully re-created my admin account. I really really appreciated it!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it helped ! Remember to mark the anwser as "accepted" if it solved your problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

> I have the backup

A database backup?

If so, restore it with phpmyadmin or adminer in your hosts Cpanel. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Restoring_Your_Database_From_Backup

There are ways to add an admin account via those database tools - see http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-a-wordpress-database/  - but it's much easier to restore the database backup.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!I have backup of all the files of wordpress.

Comment: Does this mean a database backup? Thank you.